# Qual a diferença da palavra-chave let e var em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estava estudando sobre Redux, e percebi que no código existiam muitas variáveis sendo declaradas precedidas por let, em vez de var.

Eu fiquei na dúvida, qual a diferença entre as duas declarações abaixo?

```
var variavel1;
let variavel2;
```